# Does anyone have any advice for a future vegan dog-food factory business plan?

Tags: nutrition, food, vitamins-and-minerals, protein, pets

Since veganism has at its core caring for animals, regardless of species, it is obviously necessary to apply it to feeding animals also. In this context, does anyone have any experience with the production of vegan dog-food, mainly dry extruded kibbles?

The first item on the list would be a kibble-producing machine, i seem to be incapable of finding professional offers in this regard, only amateurish ones. Another interesting topic would be the recipe, are there any tips or tricks concerning the production of vegan kibbles?

And last, but not least, any marketing advice for such a product? Non-vegan people consider such products as fanciful treats and this is one reason why they are usually more expensive than conventional dog-food. We aim at a low-priced and nutritionally complete vegan option for dogs.

Thank you

Comment: the kibble machine would be the same for any type of food, and this site is no place to be asking about the machine ... for the recipe, you should hire a veterinary nutritionist ... for marketing, hire an advertising agency